# Does Isinstance Exist in Python Version 3.7?

Tags: python, isinstance

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to follow along with a python training course which was written in 3.6.1, and am writing in Python version 3.7; however, when I write isinstance, its color does not change, where as the code in the training course does.

> Is isinstance just not considered to fit in a special category anymore, or was it removed in an update?

Comment: If your run a small example about `isinstance`, you will find whether it exists. XD.

Comment: Did you actually install [Python development tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/python/) with your Visual Studio? These are not installed by default. So I suspect you will not get any Python syntax highlighting without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it still exists

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> help(isinstance)
Help on built-in function isinstance in module builtins:

isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple, /)
    Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.

    A tuple, as in ``isinstance(x, (A, B, ...))``, may be given as the target to
    check against. This is equivalent to ``isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B)
    or ...`` etc.
```

I have not seen [any indication in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) that there is a desire to remove this function.